# An output accumulator for Math Quiz in C++

Tags: c++

Ok, so I am creating a Math Quiz.  Just something basic for now, but at the end of my while loop I want to accumulate the output, meaning if you do 5 questions of addition, the output will store the expressions of all 5 questions and use a conditional operator to say if the answer is Correct or Wrong, and it will be displayed at the very end.

I have the same program in Java, but I want to switch it over to C++ since I really like C++, and desire more of it, and that is why I would like to figure this one out.

Java:

```
output += "\n" + number1 + " - " + number2 + " = " + answer + ((number1 - number2 == answer) ? " CORRECT" : " WRONG");
```

My while loop w/ the output accumulator in C++:

```
while (count <= NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {

    num1 = 1 + rand() % 50;
    num2 = 1 + rand() % 50;

    if (num1 < num2) {
        temp = num2;
        num2 = num1;
        num1 = temp;
    }

    cout << "\n"<< num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
        cout << "Right!" << endl;
        correctCount++;
    }
    else
        cout << "Wrong! Should be " << (num1 + num2) << endl;

// Increase count
count++;

    // Prepare all questions if correct or wrong, for output
    output += // The rest...
} 

//and for final output

cout << output;
```

Comment: You could look at [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). You push things onto it in the same way you use `std::cout`. Then at the end you would do `std::cout << myStringStream.str();`.

Answer (score 0):

without using any STL libraries  : just store your variable in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>


#define NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS 5

int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int count = 0;
    //Init a
    int output[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS][4];

    while (count <= NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {

        int num1 = 1 + rand() % 50;
        int num2 = 1 + rand() % 50;
        int answer = 0;

        if (num1 < num2) {
            int temp = num2;
            num2 = num1;
            num1 = temp;
        }

        std::cout << "\n"<< num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> answer;

        if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
            std::cout << "Right!" << std::endl;
            //correctCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong! Should be " << (num1 + num2) << std::endl;
        }

        // Prepare all questions if correct or wrong, for output
        output[count][0] = num1;
        output[count][1] = num2;
        output[count][2] = answer;
        output[count][3] = (num1 + num2 == answer);

        // Increase count
        count++;
    } 
    for (int i =0; i < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Q" << i << " : " ;
        std::cout << output[i][0] << " + " << output[i][1];
        std::cout << " = " << output[i][2] << " . ";
        if (output[i][3])
            std::cout << "Right Answer ! " << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Wrong! Should be " << (output[i][0] +  output[i][1]) << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yea...I was hoping not to go so far as an Array, hoping for something simple.  But if I must, then it works!  Thanks georgesl.

Answer (score 0):

So, if i'm reading this correctly you want to loop through lets say 5 questions.
so you'd have something like...
5+12 =
user input
13+32 =
user input
31 + 1 =
user input
27+ 15 =
user input
11+11 =
user input

then the program would then output the following:

5+12 =  17
CORRECT
13+32 = 45
CORRECT
31 + 1 = 33
WRONG
27+ 15 = 42
CORRECT
11+11 = 11
WRONG

if thats what you want, then you can try something like this:

```
#define MAX_QUESTIONS 5
#define OPERANDS 2
#define LEFT 0
#define RIGHT 1 
int main()
{
   int ques[MAX_QUESTIONS][OPERANDS];
   int ans[MAX_QUESTIONS];
   for(int i=0; i < MAX_QUESTIONS; i++)
   {
      ques[i][LEFT] = 1 + rand() % 50;
      ques[i][RIGHT] = 1 + rand() % 50;
      if (ques[i][LEFT] < ques[i][RIGHT]) 
      {
         int temp = ques[i][RIGHT];
         ques[i][RIGHT] = ques[i][LEFT];
         ques[i][LEFT] = temp;
      }
      cout << "\n" << ques[i][LEFT] << " + " << ques[i][RIGHT] << " = " << endl;
      cin >> answer[i];
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_QUESTIONS; i++)
   {
      cout << "\n" << ques[i][LEFT] << " + " << ques[i][RIGHT] << " = " << answer[i] << "\n" << (((ques[i][LEFT] + ques[i][RIGHT]) == answer[i])?"CORRECT":"WRONG") << endl;
   }
}
```